# .click() handler reloading page instead of triggering event

Tags: jquery

I'm using CodeIgniter and trying to implement jQuery/AJAX to fire actions on my site without refreshing the page. Simply put its like Facebook posts and the **like button**.

So far I managed to put together a small script that gets the job done except it reloads the page on every third click.

I enclosed the action buttons in a `div` with an id `'post_'`+ the post's db `id`.

then I added a value attribute to the clicked link which holds the post id and the class is like.

```
<div>
<h3>User Name</h3>
<p>Post Content</p>
<div id="post_3">
 <a href="#" class="like" value="3">Like</a>
<div>
</div> 



$(".like").click(function(event){
var post = $(this).attr("value");
     var mydv = "#post_"+post;

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: 'localhost/like/'+post,
      success: function(response) {
      if (response == "Success")
        {
            $(mydv).load("localhost/newsfeed"+mydv);
          }
          else
          {
            alert("Error");
          }

        }
      });
     event.preventDefault();
  });
```

When the page reloads on the third click, its just a simple reload no feedback or process fired.

I must be doing something wrong, I just don't know what.

Comment: `$(this).attr("value");` - never do this!! always use `.val()` to get the value! or just `this.value`... Also, your URLs MUST start with `//` or `http://` - otherwise `localhost` will be treated as part of the path, not a hostname.

Comment: @ThiefMaster `this.value` wouldn't work in this instance, `anchor's` don't have a `value`

Comment: Could you post a jsfiddle link for it?

Comment: @ThiefMaster I can confirm what @billyonecan is saying, `.val()` is not working. And I added the `http://`

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice it's an `a` tag. In this case using a `value` is wrong in the first place. Use `data-value` instead and access it using `.data('value')`!

Comment: @ThiefMaster I changed the `value` to `data-value` and `.attr("value")` to `.data('value')`, thanks for the heads up, could you help me understand why I shouldn't use value?

Comment: Because adding attributes that don't exist results in invalid HTML. And my first comment about `.attr('value')` was mostly because it's the wrong way to get the current value of an input element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're replacing the contents of the `div` which contains the `a.like`. The `click` handler will not be attached to any anchor's which are added as a result of the `load()` call. You need to use event delegation:

```
$(document).on('click', '.like', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // your code
});
```

[Documentation for `.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events)

Comment: You are one hell of a genius!!!!!!! And thanks for the link to the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

- Add `event.preventDefault();` code at the top of event handler code.
- Also wrap code inside `document.ready`.
- Also Make sure jQuery is loaded.

Comment: I added `event.preventDefault();` right after `$(".like").click(function(event){` and still no change. jQuery is loaded and the code is wrapped inside `document.ready`

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `return false` (instead of `event.preventDefault();`):

```
$(".like").click(function(){
  ...
  return false;
});
```

Or as @Dipesh Parmar mentioned `event.preventDefault();` should be at the top of the handler.